# Use Artillery on socket app to capture values

Tags: artillery

I am trying to use [artillery](https://www.artillery.io/docs/get-started/core-concepts) to perf test a http-based socket endpoint. This is a real-time purchase system. My Virtual User (VU) will join a channel named `join`  with a GUID. On joining, the server sends to all VUs on the channel `currentitem`, the current item being purchased or bid. It receives the data as a JSON (the current item and bids if any to it):

```json
    [
       "currentitem",
       {         
          "itemCode":999,
          "itemCost":35,
          "bid":{
             "user":{
                "code":"M001",
                "name":"David"
             },
             "bidAmount":10
          }
       }
    ]
```

At this point, my script ought to read the JSON and extract the `bidAmount` and increment it by 5 and send a bid back to the "bid" channel with the JSON:

```json
    [
       "bid",
       {
          "user":{
             "code":"J001",
             "name":"John"
          },
          "itemCode":999,
          "bidAmount":15
       }
    ]
```

My Artillery YAML script is:

```yaml
    config:
      target: 'https://example.com:8080/'
      payload:
        path: "users.csv"
        fields:
          - "code"
          - "guid"
          - "name"
    
      phases:
        - duration: 60
          arrivalRate: 2
    
      - engine: "socketio"
        flow:
          - emit:
              channel: "join"
              data: { "guid": "{{guid}}" }
          - capture:
              json: "$[1].bidAmount"
              as: "latestBid"
          - think: 2 
          - log: "{{name}} joined"
    
      - engine: "socketio"
        flow:
          - loop:
            - emit:
                channel: "bid"
                data: { "user": { "code": "{{code}}","name": "{{name}}" },"itemCode": 999,"bidAmount": {{latestBid+5}} }
            - think: 1
            - log: "Bid"
        count: 720
```

My Q is: Artillery doesn't seem to be able to capture the socket messages back i.e. to get the `bidAmount`. The docs don't show any way to do this too. Any idea how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay, we missed this question.

The issue with the above is that you're setting the requests in two different scenarios, so they'll be randomly picked [according to weights](https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/test-script#scenarios-section). This means they never both run, and therefore won't set the variable.

The `socketio` engine allows you to specify HTTP requests within the same scenario. Here's an example of [mixing http actions with socketio](https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/engines/socketio#mixing-in-http-actions).

Essentially all you have to do is put it within the same scenario (make sure to also set the `scenarios` key), and it should work!